# Loading Annotation Processors as plugins in BUCK

Tags: java, android, buck, okbuck

I am exploring the usage of annotation processors using Buck for android.

It doesn't give me the annotated elements every time when something changes in the java library. I've used it as a plugin -

`android_library(..., plugins = ['//processor/src_apt'], annotation_processor_deps = [...])`

Just when, something in `src_apt` has changed it returns me the elements that I'm expecting.

Has somebody come across such an issue with annotation processors and Buck?